# How to use a nested struct/class type as a return value, in a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, auto

I currently writing some BST template class as execise
but a promblem I met confuses me.

Here is my code written in a header file
I only paste the part that causes the error here

```
template<typename Type>
class TestCls
{
    struct Node
    {
        Type data;
        Node* LeftChild;
        Node* RightChild;
    };
    Node* pRoot;
public:
    Node* GetNode(Node*& someroot);
};

template<typename Type>
Node * TestCls<Type>::GetNode(Node*& someroot)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

I use VS2015 to compile it, then the errors as below:

Error   C2059   syntax error: '' 
Error   C2923   'TestCls': 'Type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Type'
Error   C2923   'TestCls': 'Type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Type'
Error   C2065   'Type': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'Type': undeclared identifier

It seems the '`Node *`' in the head of the `GetNode()` function's definition isn't recognized by the compiler.

However if I use auto return type like this:

```
auto TestCls<Type>::GetNode(Node*& someroot)->Node*&
{
    return NULL;
}
```

The code will be compiled successfully.

So what's wrong in the first version?
How I properly use a nested struct/class type as a return value?

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename Type>
typename TestCls<Type>::Node * TestCls<Type>::GetNode(Node*& someroot)
```

`Node` is scoped inside the class template. `typename` is needed because it is a type that depends on the `Type` parameter. This is all avoided with the trailing return type case, because it looks up `Node` in the scope that you already specified in `TestCls<Type>::GetNode`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you write

```
template<typename Type>
Node * TestCls<Type>::GetNode(Node*& someroot)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

what is **before** the name of the method (`GetNode`) is outside the scope of name resolution of the class. So you have to explicit it

```
template<typename Type>
typename TestCls<Type>::Node * TestCls<Type>::GetNode(Node*& someroot)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

> However if I use auto return type like this [...] The code will be compiled successfully.

Exactly.

Because using `auto`, you write `Node` after the name of the method, so you're in scope resolution of the class so there is no need to explicit it.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - you're right; i systematically forget `typename`; thanks.